# Seeing the draw using IBDesignable+UIView(storyboard) but can't see on app

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, core-graphics, ibdesignable

I'm trying to draw some dashed lines on an app but it only draws on main.storyboard with IBDesignable. When I run the app on iOS simulator, nothing shows. What's happening?

[image]

The code to draw:

```
    @IBDesignable
    class AnalogView: UIView {



        fileprivate let thickHorizontalLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        fileprivate let thinHorizontalLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        @IBInspectable var thickYCoord = 50.0
        @IBInspectable var thinYCoord = 52.5

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)

            let thickDashesPath = UIBezierPath()
            thickDashesPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: thickYCoord)) //left

            thickDashesPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 340, y: thickYCoord)) //right

            //thickHorizontalLayer.frame           = frame
            thickHorizontalLayer.path            = thickDashesPath.cgPath
            thickHorizontalLayer.strokeColor     = UIColor.black.cgColor //dashes color
            thickHorizontalLayer.lineWidth       = 20
            thickHorizontalLayer.lineDashPattern = [ 1, 83.5 ]
            //thickHorizontalLayer.lineDashPhase   = 0.25

            self.layer.addSublayer(thickHorizontalLayer)

            let thinDashesPath = UIBezierPath()
            thinDashesPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: thinYCoord)) //esquerda
            thinDashesPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 340, y: thinYCoord)) //direita

            //thinHorizontalLayer.frame            = frame
            thinHorizontalLayer.path             = thinDashesPath.cgPath
            thinHorizontalLayer.strokeColor      = UIColor.black.cgColor
            thinHorizontalLayer.lineWidth        = 15.0
            thinHorizontalLayer.fillColor        = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            thinHorizontalLayer.lineDashPattern  = [ 0.5, 7.95]
            //thinHorizontalLayer.lineDashPhase    = 0.25

            self.layer.addSublayer(thinHorizontalLayer)
```

Comment: Where's your `init(coder:)` implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the common code in a routine that is called by both `init(frame:)` and `init(coder:)`:

```
@IBDesignable
class AnalogView: UIView {

    fileprivate let thickHorizontalLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    fileprivate let thinHorizontalLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    @IBInspectable var thickYCoord: CGFloat = 50.0
    @IBInspectable var thinYCoord: CGFloat = 52.5

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        configure()
    }

    private func configure() {
        let thickDashesPath = UIBezierPath()
        thickDashesPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: thickYCoord)) //left
        thickDashesPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 340, y: thickYCoord)) //right

        thickHorizontalLayer.path            = thickDashesPath.cgPath
        thickHorizontalLayer.strokeColor     = UIColor.black.cgColor //dashes color
        thickHorizontalLayer.lineWidth       = 20
        thickHorizontalLayer.lineDashPattern = [ 1, 83.5 ]

        self.layer.addSublayer(thickHorizontalLayer)

        let thinDashesPath = UIBezierPath()
        thinDashesPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: thinYCoord)) //esquerda
        thinDashesPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 340, y: thinYCoord)) //direita

        thinHorizontalLayer.path             = thinDashesPath.cgPath
        thinHorizontalLayer.strokeColor      = UIColor.black.cgColor
        thinHorizontalLayer.lineWidth        = 15.0
        thinHorizontalLayer.fillColor        = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        thinHorizontalLayer.lineDashPattern  = [ 0.5, 7.95]

        self.layer.addSublayer(thinHorizontalLayer)
    }
}
```

I'd also suggest declaring an explicit type for your `@IBInspectable` types, or else you won't be able to adjust them in IB.

---

Personally, rather than hard coding the path width, I'd update it when the layout changes. Also, if you're going to make those properties `@IBDesignable`, you really want to update the paths if they change.

```
@IBDesignable
class AnalogView: UIView {

    fileprivate let thickHorizontalLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    fileprivate let thinHorizontalLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    @IBInspectable var thickYCoord: CGFloat = 50.0 { didSet { updatePaths() } }
    @IBInspectable var thinYCoord:  CGFloat = 52.5 { didSet { updatePaths() } }

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        configure()
    }

    private func configure() {
        layer.addSublayer(thickHorizontalLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(thinHorizontalLayer)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updatePaths()
    }

    private func updatePaths() {
        let thickDashesPath = UIBezierPath()
        thickDashesPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x, y: thickYCoord)) //left
        thickDashesPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width, y: thickYCoord)) //right

        thickHorizontalLayer.path            = thickDashesPath.cgPath
        thickHorizontalLayer.strokeColor     = UIColor.black.cgColor //dashes color
        thickHorizontalLayer.lineWidth       = 20
        thickHorizontalLayer.lineDashPattern = [1.0, NSNumber(value: Double(bounds.size.width - 1) / 4 - 1.0) ]

        let thinDashesPath = UIBezierPath()
        thinDashesPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x, y: thinYCoord)) //esquerda
        thinDashesPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width, y: thinYCoord)) //direita

        thinHorizontalLayer.path             = thinDashesPath.cgPath
        thinHorizontalLayer.strokeColor      = UIColor.black.cgColor
        thinHorizontalLayer.lineWidth        = 15.0
        thinHorizontalLayer.fillColor        = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        thinHorizontalLayer.lineDashPattern  = [0.5, NSNumber(value: Double(bounds.size.width - 1) / 40 - 0.5)]
    }
}
```

You might want to adjust the dashing to span the width, too (I'm not sure if you wanted a consistent scale or for it to span the width). But hopefully this illustrates the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Rob. I need to get rid of using hardcoded values.